# Xcode 6.3.2 fails communicating with the Member Center

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I submitted a while ago a build of an app to the App Store for beta testing with TestFlight. The build was correctly loaded in iTunes Connect and I could sent it to review for TestFlight, but I decided to make a couple of changes in code so I removed such build from review. I archived the new version I now want to upload for beta testing, and suddenly I'm getting this warning in Xcode:

> An error occurred while communicating with the Member Center. Please file a bug and include a copy of your System log from Console.app

I haven't made any change regarding my Apple Developer's account, and as I said, I was able to connect and upload an archived app a while ago... I see that I now get that same warning in Xcode's Preferences > Account when I try to refresh its details. I don't understand why is this happening, has somebody experienced the same?

Thanks

Comment: Facing same Issue today.

Comment: Facing same issue. Lets wait until maintenance done

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have also face the same issue.It seems apple is doing some *maintenance on member center.*
Try to **login with your credentials** on apple member center.
You will get message.

i believe after maintenance we will be good to go.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is temporary. You can check Apple's [System Status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) page.

Answer (score 5):

Member center is under maintenance.

Just go here: https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action and you will be redirected to http://devimages.apple.com/maintenance

And you can always check for the status of developer related Apple services here: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/